# MSP430 With VisualGDB _system_pre_init

Tags: c, msp430

I'm using VisualGDB plugin to develop firmware for my MSP430 launchpad.

When using Code Composer I can create a function called `_system_pre_init` which will get called before the main function is called. Inside the `_system_pre_init` I can stop the watchdog for example.

Does anyone know how to setup the `_system_pre_init` in VisualGDB?

Answer (score 1):

Since this compiler is based on GCC you can set the **constructor** attribute to your *pre-init* routine.

This is an example:

```
extern void my_system_pre_init(void) __attribute__((constructor));

void my_system_pre_init(void)
{
    // Do your pre-init stuff here
}
```

You can find some details on GCC atributes in this [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).